# Django field is blank in admin, but not on regular site

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following two forms:

```
class ProfileUser(SimpleProfileUser):
    photo = PhotoField(verbose_name=_('photo'))

class Client(ProfileUser):
    can_be_seen = models.BooleanField(_('can be seen by other members'), default=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Client._meta.get_field('phone').blank = True
```

What I basically have is two type of members.
I've made common class profile, where photo is not-null.

However, in Client class I want to accept empty values of photo.

This works perfectly in admin, but doesn't work on the regular site.

How can I fix that?

Code for form is:

```
class CommonClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """This form for gathering common features in both admin and member forms
    """

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = '__all__'

    full_location = MarkerLocationField(*[Meta.model._meta.get_field(key)
                                          for key in ['latitude', 'longitude', 'location']], label=_('Location'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        individual_attrs = kwargs.pop('individual_attrs', None)
        super(CommonClientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['birthday'].widget = SelectDateWidget(individual_attrs=individual_attrs)
        if self.instance:
            self.initial['full_location'] = [self.instance.latitude, self.instance.longitude, self.instance.location]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I wrote `Client._meta.get_field('phone').blank = True` after the class definition (outside it), then it works.

I think the reason is that on client side fields are initialized before calling init, while in the admin after calling init.